# Tmux with iterm2 integration won't start when invoked with tmux -CC

Tags: iterm

I'm using iterm2 Build 1.0.0.20130302 and would like to get tmux working.  I followed the instructions at:
https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/TmuxIntegration

Everything compiled and installed without incident.  When I run `tmux -CC`
I get the following:

```
** tmux mode started **

Command Menu
----------------------------
esc    Detach cleanly.
  X    Force-quit tmux mode.
  L    Toggle logging.
  C    Run tmux command.
Detached
$ control set-client-size 80,25
-bash: control: command not found
$ control set-value "affinities0=pty-8A4A5594-20D6-4AE2-A734-76075A248E63 pty-6CAAC2D6-70DB-44EF-9A14-7A50030731B4 0,pty-DD78FAE6-7E0A-49AE-BF49-67093639FEAB"
-bash: control: command not found
$ list-sessions -F "#{session_name}"
-bash: list-sessions: command not found
```

I'm not sure what to try next.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I installed tmux as part of `homebrew` and it works just fine.

Once you have `homebrew` installed

`brew install tmux` will install tmux for you.